# Legend problems with multiple points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am developing a plot that will show when a stock price crosses certain simple moving average values.

I have successfully managed to create the plot, but I am not figuring out how to make the legend show the points separately. At the moment the points overlap each other and its a mess. Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks.

[image: Stock plot using ggplot2]
Reproducible code:

```
# Read stock price data
stockdata <- read.csv("http://www.netfonds.no/quotes/paperhistory.php?paper=NEL.OSE&csv_format=txt",header=TRUE,sep = "\t")
ticker <- as.character(unique(stockdata$paper))

# Create date object and drop columns
stockdata$date <- as.Date(as.character(stockdata$quote_date),format="%Y%m%d")
stockdata$value <- NULL
stockdata$quote_date <- NULL
stockdata$paper <- NULL
stockdata$exch <- NULL
stockdata$volume <- NULL

# Create SMA using rollmean
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
testdat <- stockdata
testdat <- arrange(testdat,date)

testdat$sma100 <- rollmean(x = testdat$close,k = 100,align="right",fill = NA)
testdat$sma200 <- rollmean(x = testdat$close,k = 200,align="right",fill = NA)

# Create conditions when below/above SMA
testdat$oversma100 <- ifelse(testdat$close>testdat$sma100,1,0)
testdat$undersma100 <- ifelse(testdat$close<testdat$sma100,1,0)
testdat$oversma200 <- ifelse(testdat$close>testdat$sma200,1,0)
testdat$undersma200 <- ifelse(testdat$close<testdat$sma200,1,0)

# Dummy variable for the day when crossing below/above SMA
testdat$crossover100 <- ifelse(testdat$oversma100==1 & lag(testdat$oversma100,n = 1)==0,1,0)
testdat$crossunder100 <- ifelse(testdat$undersma100==1 & lag(testdat$undersma100,n = 1)==0,1,0)

testdat$crossover200 <- ifelse(testdat$oversma200==1 & lag(testdat$oversma200,n = 1)==0,1,0)
testdat$crossunder200 <- ifelse(testdat$undersma200==1 & lag(testdat$undersma200,n = 1)==0,1,0)

# Subset from January 1 2017
testdat <- testdat[testdat$date >= as.Date("2017-01-01"),]

# Plot stock price + SMA100 + SMA200 + all four dummy variables
ggplot(testdat, aes(x = date,y = close)) + geom_line(size=0.1) + geom_line(aes(x=date,y=sma100,colour="100 days SMA")) + geom_line(aes(x=date,y=sma200,colour="200 days SMA")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(color="red", size=14, face="bold.italic"),legend.position="bottom",
        axis.text.x = element_text(color="black", 
                                   size=10, angle=45),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color="black", 
                                   size=10, angle=45)) + scale_x_date(date_breaks="2 weeks") + scale_y_continuous(breaks = pretty(testdat$close, n = 50)) + ggtitle(label = ticker) + 
  geom_point(data = testdat[testdat$crossover200==1,],aes(x = date,y = close,color=factor(crossover200)),shape=24,size=5, fill="green") + 
  geom_point(data = testdat[testdat$crossunder200==1,],aes(x = date,y = close,color=factor(crossunder200)),shape=25,size=5, fill="red") + 
  geom_point(data = testdat[testdat$crossover100==1,],aes(x = date,y = close,color=factor(crossover100)),shape=24,size=2, fill="blue") + 
  geom_point(data = testdat[testdat$crossunder100==1,],aes(x = date,y = close,color=factor(crossunder100)),shape=25,size=2, fill="orange")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new df. Try this:

```
temp1 <- testdat[testdat$crossover200==1,]
temp2 <- testdat[testdat$crossunder200==1,]
temp3 <- testdat[testdat$crossover100==1,]
temp4 <- testdat[testdat$crossunder100==1,]
temp1$Group <- "A"
temp2$Group <- "B"
temp3$Group <- "C"
temp4$Group <- "D"
temp <- rbind(temp1, temp2)
temp <- rbind(temp, temp3)
temp <- rbind(temp, temp4)

ggplot(testdat, aes(x = date,y = close)) + geom_line(size=0.1) + geom_line(aes(x=date,y=sma100, color="100 days SMA")) + geom_line(aes(x=date,y=sma200, color="200 days SMA")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(color="red", size=14, face="bold.italic"),legend.position="bottom",
        axis.text.x = element_text(color="black", 
                                   size=10, angle=45),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color="black", 
                                   size=10, angle=45)) + scale_x_date(date_breaks="2 weeks") + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = pretty(testdat$close, n = 50)) + ggtitle(label = ticker) + 
  geom_point(data = temp,aes(x = date,y = close,fill=Group, shape=Group))  + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "test",
                      labels = c("crossover200", "crossunder200", "crossover100", "crossunder100"),
                      values = c("green", "red", "blue", "orange")) +   
  scale_shape_manual(name = "test",
                     labels = c("crossover200", "crossunder200", "crossover100", "crossunder100"),
                     values = c(24, 25, 24, 24))
```

[image]